# How to apply a dynamic name for a key in DTLforeach*?

Tags: datatool

I want to create a new command to quickly get the amount of values of a filtered column.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{datatool,xstring,siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{PI.csv}
period|gender
1|female
2|male
1,2|female
2|female
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{PI}{PI.csv}

\NewDocumentCommand{\crcCountPIs}{mmm}{%
  % #1: funding period of interest
  % #2: column of database
  % #3: value to compare against
  \DTLforeach*[%start of conditions
  \DTLisinlist{#1}{\period}% 1st condition
  \and%
  \DTLiseq{\csname #2\endcsname}{#3}% 2nd condition
  ]%end of conditions
  {PI} % database
  {\period=period,%
    \expandafter\csname #2\expandafter\endcsname=#2% %fails, but is more flexible
    %\gender=#2% works, but is not flexible
  }
  {}
  \DTLsavelastrowcount{\n}\num{\n}%
}
\begin{document}
female (period 1): \crcCountPIs{1}{gender}{female}\\
male (period 1): \crcCountPIs{1}{gender}{male}\\
female (period 2): \crcCountPIs{2}{gender}{female}\\
male (period 2): \crcCountPIs{2}{gender}{male}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the line with `\expandafter\csname #2\expandafter\endcsname=#2` which want to use a dynmic name for the key used in the comparison.

Using the static `\gender=#2` instead works and gives this (desired) result:

[image]

Comment: to inject a token deep inside another token list, you can define an auxiliary function, construct the control sequence, pass it in the auxiliary function.

Comment: can you examplify your idea with the code above, please?